# Automaticly construct keyframe data_path from property with python

Tags: scripting

I am trying to make a function that makes setting keyframes automatically for me.

However, the object properties are different from the data_path that the function keyframe insert uses.

Say i want to update the position and set a keyframe. I will have to run:

```
obj.location.x = 1 
obj.keyframe_insert( data_path = 'location' )
```

The properties and the datas are different. **It gets even worse and non intuitive for me if i try to update something like a materials alpha value.**

Is there some logic or a way to automatically find the correct data path from the property? I am a bit confused why the same property cannot be used like so:

```
obj.keyframe_insert( data_path = 'location.x' )
```

Comment: For x location `ob.keyframe_insert("location", index=0)` By defaullt index is -1 which keyframes all components if `ob.prop` is an array.  The keyframed path is a path from the ID object. `m = ob.modifiers["Array"]; m.keyframe_insert("count")` adds an fcurve with datapath `modifiers["Array"].count` to the ID object `ob`.  The id data of the modifier `m.id_data` is `ob` and `m.path_from_id('count')` is `"modifiers["Array"].count"`.  There is  `ob.path_resolve(path)` which works for `ob.path_resolve["modifiers[0].count]` _returning the value of `m.count` but not fr `"modifiers['Array'].count`